# How to use limit and offset after get() in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I want to get all of the records in the first connection to DB and then get the number of those records.

```php
$journeyItems = JourneyItem::whereIn('as_journey_id', $journeyIds->toArray())
    ->whereHas('content', function (Builder $query) {
        $query->whereIn('as_content_type_id', [6, 7]);
    })->get();
$totalRecords = $journeyItems->count(); // count=15
$journeyItems = $journeyItems->offset($start)
    ->limit($limit);

dd(journeyItems); // Error
```

> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::offset does not exist As a
>   result: It didnt work

How can i edit ?

I guess the method below is not the correct method

```
           $journeyItems = JourneyItem::whereIn('as_journey_id', $journeyIds->toArray())
                ->whereHas('content',function(Builder $query) {
                    $query->whereIn('as_content_type_id', [ 6, 7]);
                })
                ->offset($start)
                ->limit($limit)
                ->get();
            $totalRecords = JourneyItem::whereIn('as_journey_id', $journeyIds->toArray())
                ->whereHas('content',function(Builder $query) {
                    $query->whereIn('as_content_type_id', [ 6, 7]);
                })
                ->count();
```

Comment: Have you tried using the paginate function? https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#paginating-eloquent-results It gets the total records in the same query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$journeyItems` is a collection, so use [skip](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-skip) and [take](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-take). `offset` and `limit` are query builder methods.

```
$journeyItems = $journeyItems->skip($start)->take($limit);
```

Alternatively, you can use [slice](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-slice):

```
$journeyItems = $journeyItems->slice($start, $limit);
```